# Different SHFileOperation behavior in Windows 8 with FO_RENAME

Tags: winapi, windows-8.1

In Windows 7, if a rename a file to a name that already exists in the same folder, the OS will prompt "Do you want to rename "file1.txt" to "file1 (2).txt?".

In windows 8, the same code prompts "An unexpected error is keeping you from renaming the file... Error code 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect".

```
fromFile += L'\0';
destPathTemp += L'\0';
SHFILEOPSTRUCT fileOp;

ZeroMemory(&fileOp, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCT));
fileOp.hwnd = NULL; // this is a shell extension
fileOp.wFunc = func;
fileOp.pFrom = fromFile.c_str();
fileOp.pTo = destPathTemp.c_str();

SHFileOperation(&fileOp);
```

Observations:

- If I manually try the same rename scenario in Windows 8 via  the Explorer UI, it will show the same prompt as Windows 7.
- If I add flag `FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION`, it will rename the file to "file1 (2).txt", but without the UI prompt.

Is this an API change or a bug? How do I provide the same UI behavior between Windows 7 and windows 8?

Edit: Show null termination lines in snippet.

Comment: Have you tried using IFileOperation? After all, SHFileOperation has been deprecated for a long time. You also don't appear to be double null terminating which you need to fix for the removal of doubt.

Comment: If you want the prompt then you should not pass NULL for the hwnd member, it needs a window to become the owner of the dialog.  The pForm and pTo arguments are not correct, they are double-null terminated strings, you however provide only one.  Outcome of this code is unpredictable, you were probably only lucky before.  Keep the golden rule in mind, it is never a bug in the operating system :)

Comment: I actually double terminate but didn't show that part. I added it to the example. My app supported XP originally which is why I use SHFileOperation. I could look into IFileOperation.

Comment: This is a shell extension, which is why I pass NULL for hwnd. What should I do in that case?

Comment: @wtjones The handle of the active window in your process

Comment: @David Heffernan It is a shell extension and doesn't have a window.

Comment: The shell is your host process. It certainly has windows.

Comment: Looks like I can get it from LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO. Checking on it now.

Comment: No nice, adding hwnd makes no difference.

Comment: Of course it makes a difference. Now you know how to make your dialogs have an owner.

Comment: Oops, "no nice" = "No dice". I meant that it doesn't make a difference in figuring out why the behavior differs in Win 8.

Comment: You used IFileOperation right?

Comment: No I just added the hwnd.

Comment: No reason at all to expect that setting the owner would change the behaviour of the dialog. Just the window owner. Never mind.

Comment: Hey @wtjones, did you ever figure this one out? I'm currently running into the same problem in a shell extension on Windows 10.

Comment: I created a demo app with IFileOperation and I still get the same error. I haven't tried creating a custom IFileOperationProgressSink, but am starting to think that this is just the new OS-level behavior.

Comment: Any answer to this?  I've tried IFileOperation with a variety of flags, set ownerwindow, etc.. and it doesn't work as expected either.  I tried MoveItem as well but that just asks to overwrite.