# IFileOperation: How can you tell if a rename of a folder merged with another?

Tags: windows-shell, shfileoperation

When you use `IFileOperation` to rename a *directory* that matches the name of another directory it offers to merge.  If you choose yes, it merges but no indication of the fact that it merged with another one.   Is there an easy way to tell?

You can tell it to rename on collision but it doesn't ask, it just does it.  Is there a way for it to ask if wants a new name vs merge?

When you rename a *file* that conflicts with another, it doesn't offer user a choice, it just errors out.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216926/different-shfileoperation-behavior-in-windows-8-with-fo-rename) for details

Comment: Have you implemented IFileOperationProgressSink ? Post calls may be different.

Comment: No because it only had a prerename and postrename type function, I didn't see any option there to tell me it merged or a method to ask if to use a different name on collision, etc..  If you look at the link that issue also exists, but win10 file explorer actually shows the older win7 message, so what are they using?

Comment: Have you tried it or not?

Comment: No, there is nothing there unless you're saying that's how it works, do you have an answer/sample that works?